# How to keep service running in background in Android O?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, background-service, android-8.0-oreo

I need to keep a service running in background. This service is used to keep a Socket.IO/MQTT connection. In versions previous to Android O there were no problem keeping the service alive, but in Android O this is not possible because of the [background execution limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background).

Is there any way to keep the services running, besides foreground service?

Comment: Nope. You'd need a persistent notification as a foreground service to keep it consistently running.

Comment: Background execution limit was made especially to counter heavy battery drain of multiple sockets. Otherwise resort to periodic jobs.

Comment: Your service can run in the background for *5 seconds* before you need to attach a notification to it. You might wanna read all about [Android O background limitatons](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background)

Comment: are you solve this issue? @Mariano Cordoba

Comment: @RevathiManoharan no. I'm using a foreground service for persistent connections and workmanager for tasks that are executed at fixed rates.

Comment: Ok let try jobIntent too.but my redmi note pro device working with when app fully closed i tried to push notify then my app got wokeup..It's achieved without using job intent here i used only startForegroundService.but same scenario not working in One plus device.i thought its devices specific problem.so u have to try  someother android devices too

Comment: In redmi note 5 pro while app is in background when I tried push notification its working

Answer (score 0):

You should use Firebase Cloud Messaging to push data from a server, this is to prevent all apps opening their own connection and staying active, draining the battery and filling up the RAM for no value to the user. Your app should be no exception to that.

For short lived connections (minutes), or user sessions (minutes, too, unless the user stays active longer), a foreground service might be a solution.

Out of curiosity, what is your use case for wanting a "persistent connection"?

Comment: I need to keep track of the presence of the user. I don't think FCM would help in this case, probably the best choice is to use a foreground service.

Comment: What do you consider "presence of the user"?

Comment: Also, do you really need it to be sent over the internet in real-time (I mean seconds, which still depends on network availability)?

Comment: By presence i mean if the user is online or not. And yes, i need it to be near-real-time.

Comment: That doesn't answer my first question. I can rephrase it this way: When do you consider the user is no longer online, and when do you consider he is back online?